# Rotate a group of objects

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

Im using KineticJS and im trying to rotate the group.When i rotate for the first time,offset is right and it rotates in the way i want.When i change size of a rectangle inside the group then try to rotate it gets back to previous center point or offset.
Anyone can help!?
Code:

**//selectedShape in this case is Rectangle inside the group,when i

//resize this rectangle then try to rotate group it changes a bit**

```
            selectedShape.setPosition(0, 0);               
            var offsetX = selectedShape.getWidth() / 2;
            var offsetY = selectedShape.getHeight() / 2;

            group.setOffset(offsetX, offsetY);

            if (isForRotate)
            {
                 group.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
            }
```

//reseting anchor positions after rotate

```
            topLeft.setPosition(selectedShape.attrs.x, selectedShape.attrs.y);
            topRight.setPosition(Number(selectedShape.attrs.x) + Number(selectedShape.getWidth()), selectedShape.attrs.y);
            bottomLeft.setPosition(selectedShape.attrs.x, Number(selectedShape.attrs.y) + Number(selectedShape.getHeight()));
            bottomRight.setPosition(Number(selectedShape.attrs.x) + Number(selectedShape.getWidth()), Number(selectedShape.attrs.y) + Number(selectedShape.getHeight()));
           ![enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear to me what you want but rotation is an absolute value so you should propably use something like:

```
var rotation=selectedShape.getRotation();
selectedShape.setRotation(-rotation);
```

to restore to 0;